# How to connect mongodb local server?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am on Linux Mint 17.1.
I run a Meteor js server that runs a MongoDB in its application stack. 
(all on the local machine)
I installed MongoChef (on the local machine) and without setting any parameter myself, it was able to test the connection with MongoDB.

But when I want to use MongoChef, I need to connect to the database. It is in the list, but seems not to connect.

Do I miss something in the setup?
Is there a way to know the exact port of the MongoDB server? 
Can MongoChef access it in parallel of the Meteor app?
Any insight welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the connexion port to the Meteor default: `3001`.

No problem for accessing your mongoDB collections while you are running your server.